# Match two collections dynamically by a criteria

Tags: c#

I have a collection of filter criteria objects with each criteria having a name (data object property name) and value property. I have another collection (my data objects) and I need to filter this collection to return data objects which matches the filter criteria.The properties are string values so there is no worry on the type. How can I do this?

Below is the code:

```
public class FilterCriteria
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
    }

  public class DataObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }



public static void Match()
        {
            var criteria1 = new FilterCriteria() {ColumnName = "Name", ColumnValue = "abc"};
            var criteria2 = new FilterCriteria() { ColumnName = "Name", ColumnValue = "xyz" };
            var criteriaCollection = new List<FilterCriteria> {criteria1, criteria2};

            var data1 = new DataObject() {Name = "xyz"};
            var data2 = new DataObject() { Name = "abc" };
            var data3 = new DataObject() { Name = "def" };
            var dataCollection = new List<DataObject> {data1, data2, data3};

            //filter datacollection by the criterias, match any data object with Name property equal to column value
            //After the matching I will get the result as data1 & data2.
        }
```

Thanks,
-Mike

NOTE:The FilterCriteria will be serialized to disk using xml serialization.

Comment: Looks like a really poor data model. the FilterCriteria class should contain a `public Func<DataObject,bool>` property which you could use in a `.Where()` method. Otherwise you'll have to use reflection to get property values from the `DataObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get property from its name stored in string you have to use Reflection, for example:

```
DataObject someDataObject = ...;
typeof(DataObject).GetProperty("SomePropertyName").GetValue(someDataObject)
```

Then, combining it with LINQ:

```
var filtered = dataCollection.Where(obj => 
                    criteriaCollection.Any(cond => obj.GetType()
                                                      .GetProperty(cond.ColumnName)
                                                      .GetValue(obj)
                                                      .Equals(cond.ColumnValue)))
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: It does't compile for me

Comment: No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Change to `.GetValue(obj, null)` as single parameter version was added in .NET 4.5